# getting out of range exception in bool array(c#)

Tags: c#

im trying to use random number to to pull 30 strings out of a array of 58 strings and am using a bool array to check and make sure the same number is not called twice. the method and the program always crashes with a index out of range error. here is the method.

```
        static string[] newlist(string[] s)
        {
            string[] newlist = {};
            bool[] issearched = new bool[s.Length];
            Random callorder = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
            {
               int number = callorder.Next(0, s.Length);
               if (issearched[number] == false)
               {
                   newlist[number] = s[number];
                   issearched[number] = true;//this is where it always crashes even though the ide says issearced has 58 elements and the random number is always smaller than that.
               }
               else
                   i--;
            }
            return newlist;              
        }
```

im sure its simple but i can't figure out why index of 8 is outside the range of the array of 58.

Comment: No your array newlist is not of 58 elements length.

Comment: its of the lengeth of [s.length] which is 58. visual studio says 58 when i scroll over it at the break point.

Comment: Check again that is the length of issearched not the length of newlist, you are assigning to newlist not to issearched, the exception is in the newlist assignement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array newlist (what a confusing name) has no space to store anything.
This line

```
  string[] newlist = {};
```

declares the array but without setting the space to store any element, so when you try to use the indexer on it you get the exception.

I suggest to use a different approach to find 30 strings from your passed array.
Using a `List<string>` and continue to add to this list until you have 30 elements in the list

```
    static string[] newlist(string[] s)
    {
        List<string> selectedElements = new List<string>();
        bool[] issearched = new bool[s.Length];
        Random callorder = new Random();
        while(selectedElements.Count  < 30))
        {
           int number = callorder.Next(0, s.Length);
           if (!issearched[number])
           {
               selectedElements.Add(s[number]);
               issearched[number] = true;
           }
        }
        return selectedElements.ToArray();
    }
```

If you prefer to use arrays as from your method then a couple of fixing is required to your code

```
static string[] newlist(string[] s)
{
    string[] newlist = new string[30];
    bool[] issearched = new bool[s.Length];
    Random callorder = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
       int number = callorder.Next(0, s.Length);
       if (issearched[number] == false)
       {
           newlist[i] = s[number];
           issearched[number] = true;
       }
       else
           i--;
    }
    return newlist;
}
```

- The newlist array is declared to have space to store 30 elements
- The for loops for 30 times (not 31 as from your current code)
- The newlist should use as indexer the value of the variable `i`

Comment: thanks that fixed the issue. i guess i dident read what the ide was saying the problem was correctly but its running now. i bet i look dumb lol ^-^;

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're actually crashing here:

```
newlist[number] = s[number];
```

Replace

```
string[] newlist = {};
```

With

```
string[] newlist = new string[s.Length];
```

Your newlist size is 0 elements, nowhere are you allocating enough space for it.

Also your program will go into an infinite loop if the input size is less than 31 elements.

Comment: thanks that did it. im still new to programing and havent become too good at debugging yet so i must have been miss understanding what the ide was saying the problem was.